# How to use Alt+Shift to switch keyboard layouts?

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10, with the new keyboard handling system. The little "switch keyboard" option does not let me set it to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>. How can I get this keyboard binding, as I have absolutely no interest in using the Mac-esque <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> combo?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

A confirmed [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-keyboard/+bug/1218322) in Ubuntu 13.10 prevents users from switching layouts using combinations like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> etc.

The bug affects many people, its importance is set to "High", so we may expect that an official fix will be released soon. You can [subscribe](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1218322/+subscribe) to notifications about this bug on launchpad.net, so that you receive an email when it's done.

Currently, a [patch](https://launchpad.net/~attente/+archive/modifier-only-input-switch) aimed at resolving this issue is being tested. By now it seems to work for most users, though certain problems remain. To install the patch, use the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:attente/modifier-only-input-switch
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

A system reboot was needed in my case to make it work (simple log out and log in may be sufficient).

**Note:** Originally, the patch was located at ppa:attente/1218322. If you have previously installed it from there, you can first purge it as follows

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:attente/1218322
```

and then execute the three commands above.

Alternatively, you may consider using a combination containing a non-modifier key (a letter, digit, space): try, for instance, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> (this will work without installing any patches).

Note that the keyboard shortcuts for switching layouts still do not work on lock screen (it is a  [separate bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/1244548)). If you are stuck on lock screen and unable to enter the password because of the wrong layout, simply click the language indicator icon on the right of the password field.

Comment: I installed the attente's patch hoping that it could bring back my beloved (Left ALT) switch combo. But after reboot it did not work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for this, really frustrating how such an essential thing was broken

Comment: Creator of the ppa says it has been superseded by [this one](https://launchpad.net/~attente/+archive/modifier-only-input-switch)

Comment: Did not work for me with Ubuntu GNOME 13.10 :(

Comment: The mentioned ppa fix, in line with the bug's [description](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1218322), does indeed "provide some relief". However, it comes with its own drawbacks: sometimes, it messes up the editing (the text I type gets entered in a different place) or freezes the system for seconds when I switch keyboard layout. Does anyone know if a proper fix is or will be available? Does the upcoming Ubuntu 14.04 have a similar bug and need a similar fix?

Comment: I've just upgraded from 13.04 to 13.10 and I didn't need to install the patch.

Comment: I have Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 and the same issue. The PPA does not work, simply no files will be installed.

Answer (score 26):

Many thanks to [William Hua (attente)](https://launchpad.net/~attente) for his [Modifier-only input switch PPA](https://launchpad.net/~attente/+archive/modifier-only-input-switch). As he said, he will keep the PPA up-to-date until a correct fix for [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-keyboard/+bug/1218322) is released.

After I added this PPA to my list of sources using the following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:attente/modifier-only-input-switch
```

and after I upgraded my system using:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I could change the default <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> keyboard shortcut to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>:

[image: Text Entry]

Comment: Creator of the ppa says it has been superseded by [this one](https://launchpad.net/~attente/+archive/modifier-only-input-switch)

Comment: Is this solution works in `ubuntu 15.04` too? I have this problem in this version too.

Comment: Does it work on Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 14):

In Ubuntu 16.04 with Gnome 3.18, you can make it work using `dconf Editor` (should work for previous versions as well since the bug seems to be quite old):

1. Go to `org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings`
2. change `switch-input-source` (or `switch-input-source-backward`) to `['<Shift>Alt_L']` (or `['<Alt>Shift_L']`)
3. Enjoy!
   [image: dconf editor]

Comment: This was my case and it's helped. wondering why such things not fixed...

Comment: This solution also works in ubuntu 19.04

Comment: You can also use a terminal: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Shift>Alt_L']"`

Comment: The solution descibed by Mohamed Y. above worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04. I switched to `'<Alt>Shift_L'`. The only note is that the command to start the editor in the terminal is: 'dconf-editor'. Starting it may require installing a 'dconf-editor' package if it wasn't yet installed.

Answer (score 3):

*In Ubuntu 12.04 LTS*, in the *Keyboard Layout Options* window I could select **Key(s) to change layout** and *mark* the binding of my choice. I use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to ***toggle*** the layout from the keyboard itself without having to use mouse cursor to select the required layout from the panel indicator. The same key combo seemed to work to serf through or select between multiple layouts. *(But in Ubuntu 13.10 it wasn't so easy.)*
[image: snap5]

---

## In Ubuntu 13.10

In the *Keyboard* settings window, under *Shortcuts* tab, I select *Typing*. The default for *Switch to next source* is <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> which didn't seem be working for me and so by clicking on it and I assigned a *New Accelerator...*, to change to next ***L***ayout (I used <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>).

(Then I assigned something similar for Switch to previous source *using the same preferred layout*, and then began to test them. **Switching from the preferred layout to the alternate worked but the reverse did not**. Please refer the next step for the fix.)
[image: saucy1]

**The Fix:** After assigning <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> for *"Switch to next source"* using my **preferred layout (A)**, I *changed my keyboard layout* to the **alternative layout (B)** and then assigned the combination to *"Switch to previous source"* (for which I used <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>). Then I tested them, and they work fine. (Maybe disabling *"Switch to previous source"* would work too.)

The new accelerators for the key combos that I used looks like this:
[image: saucy2]

I could then switch to layout (A) using <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and back to layout (B) using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

Comment: Works in Ubuntu 20.04