# How to switch input language with Caps Lock in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, 13.10

Ubuntu 13.10 has a different menu for Text Entry.

I'm using Caps Lock for swiching language input. After upgrade from 13.04 I'm not able to switch languages with Caps Lock.

Looks like upgrade broke previous settings (annoying). How do you make Caps Lock switch languages again using UI Settings? `setxkbmap` magic is not suitable.

Comment: It might be a bug.  Take a look at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-keyboard/+bug/1215826

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use alt+shift combo to switch keyboard layout in 13.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/356357/how-to-use-altshift-combo-to-switch-keyboard-layout-in-13-10)

Comment: It *is* a duplicate, provided OP adds CapsLock to title.

Comment: Given that this is helpful for users who want an answer rather than reading through > 400 comments of the devs of 10 packages who were negligent enough to essentially break ubuntu's usability for users internationally and release packages with known bugs, I don't think this is off topic. I think it's a high quality question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Ubuntu 13.04 this was simple: go to **System Setting** → **Keyboard Layout** → **Options** → **Key(s) to change layout** and tick <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>:

[image: Keyboard Layout Options]

But in Ubuntu 13.10, **Keyboard Layout**, now called **Text Entry**, has undergone many changes, and for the moment, until a  a correct fix for [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-keyboard/+bug/1218322) will be released, is a little bit more complicated to switch input language with <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>.

After I added the following PPA to my list of sources using the following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:attente/1218322
```

and after I upgraded my system using:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I was able to change the default <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> keyboard shortcut to <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>:

[image: Text Entry]

Many thanks to [William Hua (attente)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAynS.png) for his [Input source switching PPA](https://launchpad.net/~attente/+archive/1218322). As he said, he will keep the PPA up-to-date until a correct fix for [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-keyboard/+bug/1218322) is released.

Comment: Any chances for stateless layout switching? I.e. first layout on caps, second on shift+caps. This was easy as pie with the dialog you've shown, but not in Saucy anymore. WTF?

Comment: It's fixed now. Turns out it was some kind of spec miss or just a bug.