# how to change language with alt+shift ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, language-support

With older ubuntu changing languages with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> was easy to enable but on 13.10 I can not do this task at all
can any one help me ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello you can find this answer in the following link.

[Askubuntu Alt Shift Combo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356357/how-to-use-altshift-combo-to-switch-keyboard-layout-in-13-10)

Seems the solution is simply adding space to the combination  keys that you want to use for shortcuts.

The following link confirms the issue

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-keyboard/+bug/1218322