# I can't change keyboard layout ubuntu 13.10

Tags: keyboard, 13.10, layout

I ve just installed ubuntu 13.10 and I've installed my local language keyboard and I can't find a way to simply change from one to another for example with the "traditional" keys <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>!

Comment: What does `dconf read /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-input-source` say? You may need to install `dconf-tools` for the command to work.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://askubuntu.com/q/356357/204380 There is a known bug with the `Alt+Shift` shortcut.