# How to change Keyboard layout in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, keyboard-layout

After upgrading to 13.10 today, my favorite layout switch (left ALT) has stopped working. 
I am using Gnome-fallback (hate the new tabletish trend of Unity ang Gnome 3)

After checking the layout options, I noticed that it has dramatically changed in 13.10. 
I could not find layout shortcut change options anymore.  Now I am wondering how to define the shortcut again?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use alt+shift combo to switch keyboard layout in 13.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/356357/how-to-use-altshift-combo-to-switch-keyboard-layout-in-13-10)

Comment: @Radu I did not ask about keyboard combination. so this question is different from the one you linked.

Answer (score 3):

Settings > Text Entry, click on the each relevant text box and specify your shortcut.

[image]