# How to activate the sign @

Tags: keyboard

I have just installed Ubuntu on my laptop, but I can not type @ ! How do I activate the sign @ on my laptop?

Comment: See "How to change Keyboard layout in Ubuntu 13.10?" http://askubuntu.com/questions/361947/how-to-change-keyboard-layout-in-ubuntu-13-10

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I type an \`@\` (at sign) symbol?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/103220/how-do-i-type-an-at-sign-symbol)

Comment: On my keyboard, it's Shift F2

Answer (score 1):

In ubuntu you cannot type @ by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, if that is your problem.

To type `@` you will instead need to press <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You may have default USA keyboard map, try pressing the " (double quote) key. You can change the map anytime through the options.