# Problem setting keyboard shortcuts after upgrade to Saucy

Tags: upgrade, keyboard, keyboard-layout, 13.10, keyboard-accelerators

After upgrading from Ubuntu Raring to Saucy, the new Keyboard applet changed my keyboard shortcut for cycling between keyboard layouts to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, but this new shortcut doesn't do anything. When trying to set my old shortcut (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>), it interprets that as <kbd>Mod4</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Hyper</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Is this a know problem, and is there any way I can get my old shortcut back? I need to cycle between 3 different keyboard layouts frequently (sometimes several times an hour), so having to use the mouse for this is a major regression in my work flow.

Comment: known bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-keyboard/+bug/1218322, even a ppa trying to fix it https://launchpad.net/~attente/+archive/1218322

Comment: Oh thanks, saw that and posted a reply myself while you were writing your comment.

Comment: cheers, probably also duplicate to http://askubuntu.com/questions/356357/how-to-use-altshift-combo-to-switch-keyboard-layout-in-13-10

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, there's [already a bug report on Launcpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-keyboard/+bug/1218322).

Apparently, combinations containing an alphanumeric character work.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make it work try CTRL + SPACE  or ALT + SPACE these combination is working till the bug fixes.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can find this answer in the following link.

How to use alt+shift combo to switch keyboard layout in 13.10

Seems the solution is simply adding space to the combination keys that you want to use for shortcuts.

The following link confirms the issue

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-keyboard/+bug/1218322