# changing 'switch language keys' no longer working in 13.10

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, 13.10

I have Ubuntu 13.10 installed.
from Text Entry Settings I added Arabic to keyboard layouts then tried to change the 'Switch to next source using: ' field. I tried to set it to Shift+Caps Lock and Alt+Shift and other combinations but no luck, It does not change,just leaves a blank field.

I tried to change the keys from Keyboard Settings > Typing > Switch to next source, same results, whatever combinations I try it leaves the field disabled.

how do I change the keys and fix this problem ?? I never had this problem in any of previous Ubuntu releases.

Hint: I had Ubuntu 13.10 when it was still in Beta and then updated to the last release, This problem existed all along. I don't know if that can be relevant but just in case.

Comment: There's a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1226962) for this issue.

Comment: @chaskes forgive me, I'm not that experienced with linux. Should I wait until this bug fix is applied in an update or try to install or run it myself? if the second, How?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use alt+shift combo to switch keyboard layout in 13.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/356357/how-to-use-altshift-combo-to-switch-keyboard-layout-in-13-10)

Comment: Ignore the answer below, this is the bug report you are looking for : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-keyboard/+bug/1218322

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been filed as a bug report: [Hotkeys not functional in non-latin keyboard layout in 13.10](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1226962)  For now, the bug report gives the following workaround:

> Workaround for some system hotkeys and two layouts (english and non-latin): rebind all hotkeys in your local layout. For example instead of ctrl+alt+t use ctrl+alt+τ (greek tau). That hotkey still work with english layout. If you use english and two different non-latin layouts this workaround helps only with one of them.

You could also use the indicator on the menubar to switch layouts rather than the hotkeys.

**Update**:

As mentioned by levesque, there is [another bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1218322) listed that addresses this issue. The solution provided in the bug thread is as follows:

```
A PPA which should provide some relief for this issue is available at https://launchpad.net/~attente/+archive/modifier-only-input-switch. To install:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:attente/modifier-only-input-switch
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
(log out, log in)

If the packages improve the situation for you, you can pin them using:

sudo apt-mark hold compiz
sudo apt-mark hold gnome-settings-daemon
sudo apt-mark hold unity

If the packages don't work for you, you can purge them using:

sudo ppa-purge ppa:attente/modifier-only-input-switch
```

Comment: I believe this is the bug, and not what you linked to - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1218322 - FYI, I installed a custom patch (don't remember which), and now I can set the combo to Super-Shift. (Nothing else works/worked, not Super-Space nor Alt-Shift)

Comment: @chaskes added the info mentioned by levesque as that helped solve this problem for me, and the question is closed, so i couldn't put it in another answer. hope that's alright.