# Sublime text - no shortcuts working on non-latin layout, 12.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, sublime-text

I have fresh ubuntu 12.04 and Sublime text 2 installation. There are two keyboard layouts: English and Russian. If I switch on Russian one: no shortcuts are working, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and so on. However, it works well on English layout. I have noticed strange behaviour: if I switch window focus to another application: it starts working! Of course I can remap ALL key bindings to Russian letters (but it is headache!). I am sure that it is some bug, or program conflict. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

As a temporary workaround you can simply open and then close a new tab in Sublime.
After that some hotkeys are starting to work.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug: [Hotkeys not functional in non-latin keyboard layout in 13.10 and 14.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1226962). Nasty one, and hope fix comes through soon.

See also the info in the "[changing 'switch language keys' no longer working in 13.10 [closed]](https://askubuntu.com/q/362167/38585)" Q&A.