# Ubuntu 13.10 lost layout switch shortcut

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, 13.10

After upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10, my keyboard layout switch shortcut not functioning any more. I used to use <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key.

I tried to redefine it but could not find any. The layout option settings page has changed and it does not seem to have any possibility to define the short cut.

I heavily rely on this feature and it is a pain that each time I need to take mouse on control panel language icon to switch layout. Really appreciate if you help me to resolve this.

Comment: Sorry, I found answer here: http://askubuntu.com/a/360843/19019. Feel free to answer by adding that the shortcut can be set through: Kayboard> Typing > Shortcuts > Switch to next Rescource