# How to use the new Keyboard Switcher

Tags: keyboard

The keyboard switcher no longer works for me; I used to switch between keyboard layouts (from English to other languages) the same way as I do on Windows, using Alt-Shift.

It no longer seems to accept this combination, and I can't figure out how to set this up.

Is this a known bug?

Comment: It is a known bug. See http://askubuntu.com/a/360843/27968

Answer (score -1):

Use the keys combination: <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to next keyboard layout or <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to previous.