# Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V don't work in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 13.10

I've installed the package from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356357/how-to-use-altshift-combo-to-switch-keyboard-layout-in-13-10) to solve the problem of not changing the layout of the keyboard in 13.10 , after that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> aren't working anymore.

Comment: Have Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V stopped working in all applications? Note that e.g. in the terminal the key combination is Ctrl+Shift+C/V.

Comment: yes they stopped working in all applications

Comment: In my case, even choosing "Copy" and "Past" in the right click does not work. Only "copy to", "Move to" works. Any idea?

Comment: In my case its ubuntu 14.04 and also ctrl+t ctrl+r are not working in browsers. Ctrl+c works in terminal stops the task but ctrl+shift+c does not work either as ctrl+c in other apps

Comment: Also happening in Ubuntu 16.04 from time to time.