# 13.10 - Is it possible to revert keyboard-related software to 13.04?

Tags: keyboard, 13.10, ibus

I've been hopelessly trying to get ibus to play nice with 13.10's updated input method application chain.

I tried just using ibus as the default input method , but when I try to change keyboard shortcuts I end up with this

[image]

I don't know if its relevant but I did apply the solution to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356357/how-to-use-altshift-combo-to-switch-keyboard-layout-in-13-10) to try and fix a related keyboard issue.

What's more, whether or not I use ibus as an input style (as definied in the "Languages and Region" panel), when anthy is activated it doesn't seem to capture any of the keyboard commands.

I feel like I have completely broken every aspect of keyboard management in my ubuntu install, so I have two questions:

- Would it be possible to revert the keyboard stuff to 13.04 management?
- What would I need to do to bring my keyboard stuff back to a "vanilla" 13.10 install's config?

I'm surprised at how broken the keyboard management became in 13.10. I don't understand why they'd break things as fundamental as keyboard shortcuts for no noticeable gains.