# Stateless layout switching in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, 13.10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, gnome-settings-daemon

[image: screenshot]

I use extensively two keyboard layouts (latin for English, and cyrillic for Ukrainian and Russian), and it bothers me to experience my [mode errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_%28computer_interface%29#Mode_errors) because of the additional bit of UI state: **the current layout**.

I used to eliminate them completely by using *stateless* layout switching, whereby one has no `next layout` action (as such an action is based on the *current state*, which is easy to forget for the user, and so leads to errors), rather only two actions:

1. enable latin layout;
2. enable cyrillic layout.

This was trivially accomplishable in pre-Saucy releases. As illustrated on the screenshot above.

However, that settings window [was destroyed](https://askubuntu.com/q/356357/9061) in Saucy.

How do I get my stateless switching now?

Comment: It seems to me I will have to write this menu as an application soon as I need it for my users. Задолбали с такими "улучшениями"

Comment: @BarafuAlbino this menu is more or less completely available as part of `gnome-tweak-tool`. Alas, settings there didn't quite work for me in 14.04.

Comment: @ulidtko, what did you end up with?

Answer (score 5):

This command will set layout to the first one (It works nicely with Unity/Gnome Indicator, Ubuntu 13.10/14.04):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 0
```

You can use tweak tools, gnome action, compiz action plugin..etc to create a keyboard shortcut for it.

Layouts are indexed starting from 0. So you can make shortcut for any layout in the list.

You can use this to create complex script for last layout without giving an index:

```
 gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources
```

Like:

```
 gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current $(($(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources | grep -Po "'[[:alpha:]]+'\)" | wc -l)-1))
```

Comment: This is *something*, but based on my previous experience with "command" shortcuts I have a suspicion that spawning processes  will not be the most pleasant way of switching keyboard layout. Especially during those *loaded* moments of the system, when it frantically swaps memory back and forth; having *seconds* of latency for layout switching is not going to be acceptable. I'd definitely prefer something which persists in memory and reacts quickly.

Comment: why don't you give it a try? I don't think that you will have seconds of latency, even when the system is under heavy load. It is a system call nonetheless, but as I've inspected the gsettings source code in the past, it really does harmless things and once it changes the value some corresponding (already running) application takes care of the rest.

Comment: @hakermania at dark times when pulseaudio didn't work well on my system, I've been using pure alsa, plus a custom volume regulator built on the same approach (spawning scripts via hotkeys). *Mostly* it worked fine, but *at times* it reacted so dreadfully late, that this caused not only annoyment but also embarassment (imagine not being able to timely turn off, say, an adult video soundtrack, etc). Now I'm soft of reluctant to this approach.

Answer (score 5):

The keyboard options in Ubuntu and GNOME are nothing but a frontend to the X keyboard extension (XKB). If you are fine with configuring things manually you can easily reenable all of the now-missing options with a `setxkbmap` command line.

For instance, to set a non-modal switch between Russian and English keyboard layouts you can use the following command:

```
setxkbmap -layout us,ru -option grp:shift_caps_switch
```

This will enable these XKB settings for the current session. If you want to make the change permanent you will have to [add the command above to your startup applications](https://askubuntu.com/q/48321/81372).

If you are interested in the various other settings you can control with `setxkbmap`, I recommend going though the manual (`man setxkbmap`) and taking a look at `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst`. The latter documents all different ways to configure the compose key, keyboard layout toggle, etc.

The following is the `base.lst` section on keyboard layout switching:

```
! option
  grp                  Key(s) to change layout
  grp:switch           Right Alt (while pressed)
  grp:lswitch          Left Alt (while pressed)
  grp:lwin_switch      Left Win (while pressed)
  grp:rwin_switch      Right Win (while pressed)
  grp:win_switch       Any Win key (while pressed)
  grp:caps_switch      Caps Lock (while pressed), Alt+Caps Lock does the original capslock action
  grp:rctrl_switch     Right Ctrl (while pressed)
  grp:toggle           Right Alt
  grp:lalt_toggle      Left Alt
  grp:caps_toggle      Caps Lock
  grp:shift_caps_toggle Shift+Caps Lock
  grp:shift_caps_switch Caps Lock (to first layout), Shift+Caps Lock (to last layout)
  grp:win_menu_switch  Left Win (to first layout), Right Win/Menu (to last layout)
  grp:lctrl_rctrl_switch Left Ctrl (to first layout), Right Ctrl (to last layout)
  grp:alt_caps_toggle  Alt+Caps Lock
  grp:shifts_toggle    Both Shift keys together
  grp:alts_toggle      Both Alt keys together
  grp:ctrls_toggle     Both Ctrl keys together
  grp:ctrl_shift_toggle Ctrl+Shift
  grp:lctrl_lshift_toggle Left Ctrl+Left Shift
  grp:rctrl_rshift_toggle Right Ctrl+Right Shift
  grp:ctrl_alt_toggle  Alt+Ctrl
  grp:alt_shift_toggle Alt+Shift
  grp:lalt_lshift_toggle Left Alt+Left Shift
  grp:alt_space_toggle Alt+Space
  grp:menu_toggle      Menu
  grp:lwin_toggle      Left Win
  grp:rwin_toggle      Right Win
  grp:lshift_toggle    Left Shift
  grp:rshift_toggle    Right Shift
  grp:lctrl_toggle     Left Ctrl
  grp:rctrl_toggle     Right Ctrl
  grp:sclk_toggle      Scroll Lock
  grp:lctrl_lwin_rctrl_menu LeftCtrl+LeftWin (to first layout), RightCtrl+Menu (to second layout)
```

The various XKB settings are also documented under `man 7 xkeyboard-config`.

---

If `setxkbmap` doesn't work for you you can try setting the XKB options through `dconf` instead:

1. Install `dconf-editor` (`sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`)
2. Open dconf editor from your dash and navigate to *org* → *gnome* → *desktop* → *input-sources*
3. Add your XKB settings to `xkb-options` in form of an array. E.g.: `['grp:shift_caps_switch']`

Source: [Make setxkbmap preferences being set at startup](https://askubuntu.com/q/410499/81372)

Comment: `setxkbmap` has no effect on my system (probably because they use `xim` input method instead of `xinput`).

Comment: @ulidtko I added a section on configuring XKB settings via dconf. Might yield better results on your system.

Comment: This a good optiop for gnome. AFAIK `xkb-options` works only with Gnome, Unity doesn't care about. I've tested `setxkbmap` before with unity I does work for short period then it reset to Unity settings. It does work well by uninstalling `indicator-keyboard` and disabling unity layout change shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just using the Tweak Tool:

[image]

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Turns out [Cinnamon](https://linuxmint.com/) desktop has that option still! Nice.