# ibus-avro for Bengali not working in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, ibus

I've upgraded from Ubuntu 13.04 to Ubuntu 13.10, then ibus-avro for Bengali is not working.
I've tried to reinstall ibus but no success. ibus-avro Icon is showing but not sure whats the problem.

It should be working like this...
[image]

The icon on top is showing properly, but it's not working. May be there are some communication problem.

So currently after upgrade it's like this...
[image]

**As we can see the Bangla text is not appearing...**

I've tried these steps...But no hope.

`rm ~/.candidate-selections.json`

and

```
sudo killall ibus-daemon
ibus-daemon -vx
```

Then

`/usr/bin/env gjs --include-path=/usr/share/ibus-avro /usr/share/ibus-avro/main-gjs.js`

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just go to Terminal and type

`sudo apt-get install ibus-avro-saucy`

If you have not installed avro in Ubuntu 13.10 before then follow this

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/sarimkhan/xUbuntu_13.04/ ./"
```

then

```
wget -q http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/sarimkhan/xUbuntu_13.04/Release.key -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install ibus-avro-saucy
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, click the right mouse button on the icon and see if the input method can be selected. If that is the case, you are facing a problem with activation sequence.

[image]

In Ubuntu 13.10, the ibus activation key sequence has been changed to `Super-Space`. But the problem is, this works and again does not work. May be some final tweaking is still in the process. Please try `Super-Space` and see if that works for you.

Anyway, for my case, I changed the activation key sequence to the previously known `Ctrl-Space`. But due to some [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1218322), this can not be changed readily. A patch is available for this one. To install the patch, please execute,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:attente/1218322
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then reboot your system. And change key sequence to `Ctrl-Space` (or whatever else is your favorite).

The above has worked for me, perfectly.

(You may want to see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356357/how-to-use-altshift-combo-to-switch-keyboard-layout-in-13-10) for a discussion on the bug.)

Please let me know if you still face any problem.

Comment: Thx but I didn't face this problem, because I've upgraded from 13.04 to 13.10. Without any changes I've changed the sequence to Ctrl-Space.

Comment: @FaisalHaqSalafi I understand, but for my case, the input methods were not there. I also upgraded from 13.04 to 13.10. I had to add all the input methods fresh.