# Swap caps lock and Ctrl in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, keyboard, emacs, capslock

Can anyone explain how to swap <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys on Ubuntu desktop under Unity.
I use it to avoid [emacs pinky](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/17492).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The relevant option is no longer available in the settings menu in Ubuntu 13.10; this has been reported as a bug (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1218322). However, it is still possible to swap these keys using the Gnome tweak tool.

First, install gnome-tweak-tool using `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool` from a console.

Then, run it using the command `gnome-tweak-tool`, or by typing "Tweak Tool" into the dash at the top-left.

From this tool, choose the "Typing" tab on the left. Then, from the dropdown next to "Ctrl key position" on the right, choose "Swap Ctrl and Caps Lock". This should swap those two keys.

[image]

Comment: It was driving me nuts. Can't thank you enough.

Comment: Confirmed it worked for Ubuntu 18.04 and GNOME 3.28.

Answer (score 15):

```
setxkbmap -option ctrl:swapcaps
```

Will work on all linux distributions and versions. You will need to add it to your startup file to get it to run automatically when you log in.

Answer (score 2):

go to System Settings/Keyboard Layout/(language)/options

Comment: there's no such option. I can reach as far as System Settings/Keyboard/Layout Settings, however there's no "options" to be found.

Comment: can you provide a screenshot where are you looking for it? Because there's an option to swap Caps Lock with Ctrl I just checked it myself.

Comment: @JohnyD. Which version of Ubuntu are you using? I'm looking in the same place (on 13.10) and the option doesn't seem to be there. I remember seeing something similar on an older version, for sure, but I think it may have been moved at some point.

Comment: Yeah, it's a reported bug in 13.10 that this menu is missing. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1218322.

Comment: ![screenshot][1]  
                        [1]:http://s1.bild.me/bilder/260513/5820784Screenshot_from_2014-01-29_17_09_54.png

Comment: follow this thread then if it's a bug http://askubuntu.com/questions/356357/how-to-use-altshift-to-switch-keyboard-layouts-in-13-10

Answer (score 1):

`setxkbmap -option ctrl:swapcaps` will only swap <kbd>Control</kbd> and <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>. If you want both keys to simulate <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> then `gnome-tweak-tool` -> "Typing" -> "<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>". Now both keys work as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

Comment: setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps will cause both keys to be control and is independent of gnome.