# An ability to make my CAPS work as CTRL again

Tags: 13.10, keyboard, capslock

When are you going to recover the ability to make <kbd>CAPS</kbd> work like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. Like in all previous versions?

This is really critical as I am using emacs key-bindings and this is a one huge stopper and forces me to drop Ubuntu, at least until I see it fixed.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1218322

Comment: Possible dup: http://askubuntu.com/questions/412576/swap-caps-lock-and-ctrl-in-ubuntu-13-10