# Ubuntu Gnome: Can't make changing keyboard layout to crtl+shift

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I have installed Ubuntu Gnome 13.10 and I can't figure out why I can't make changing keyboard layout shortcut to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>. I have 3 languages in my input sources.
I see in `Tweak Tool` that "Key(s) to change layout" is set to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.
If I open `dconf Editor` I see that in desktop->ibus->general->hotkey the `next-engine` an `next-engine-in-menu` preferences are set to [<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>].

But somehow I have figured out that input language can be changed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. When I click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> I can see the language changing in the top right corner, but input language stays the same.
Any ideas why this can happen and how can I change it?

**UPDATE**:
Also, I have found that changing system keyboard shortcut setting works in System Settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts->Typing->Switch to next(previous) source. But I cannot set there <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> setting which I want to set. The only comfortable combination I set there was <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.
I have seen a bug on this here: [Bug #1218322: Can't set keyboard layout change to alt+shift, ctrl+shift, etc.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1218322)

Any suggestions on how it can be fixed?

Comment: possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/412576/swap-caps-lock-and-ctrl-in-ubuntu-13-10/412595#412595

Comment: not a duplicate, cause that is not the answer. read my question carefully please.

Comment: did you try this one? http://askubuntu.com/questions/356357/how-to-use-altshift-to-switch-keyboard-layouts

Comment: yes, didn't worked for me either. as I said setting 'System Settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts->Typing->Switch to next(previous) source' works, but I can't set there Ctrl+Shift option (just shows 'disabled'), but can Ctrl+Shift+Space.

Comment: I found a good workout dedicated to Lubuntu https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Keyboard but you can check it and replace it with Ubuntu there's a workout for ctrl+shift that's the last I could suggest on this bug.

Comment: Had same problem. I set the combination to Win + Space which is pretty fast and comfortable.

Comment: Nothing helps, unfortunately.