# Layout change with Alt+space on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, dconf

I am used to changing keyboard layouts with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, and worked fine until I upgraded to 14.04. I set it in the Text Entry control panel:

[image]

but it doesn't work. I suspect that  there is a conflict with some other binding, but I cant find it in dconf. How can I fix this?

I use GNOME (boooo  unity!), if this changes anything.

Comment: Alt+Space is the shortcut that opens the window menu (the same menu that is opened when you click on the title bar).

Comment: @BrunoNova I disabled that

Comment: Maybe this helps: [How to use Alt+Shift to switch keyboard layouts?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/356357/how-to-use-altshift-to-switch-keyboard-layouts)

Comment: You may want to try setting this through the "gnome-tweak-tool", but I'm not sure it will work. I think there's a problem with layout swapping in gnome. That's the main reason I use unity instead. The best I could get with gnome is switching layouts once, and then the shortcut would stop working...

Comment: Layout switching in Ubuntu gnome is definitely very buggy (and like that since years). See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1218322 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-keyboard/+bug/1240198 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1246272 ;-| I would be not surprised at all if something new is appearing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> is the standard keyboard shortcut to activate a window since IBM OS/2

<kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> is the standard keyboard shortcut to change keyboard input methods in Ubuntu

To switch both around do a:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings activate-window-menu "['<Super>space']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Alt>space']"
```

I hope you're the only one using this machine, as it's a dirty trick to play on your *old* colleagues who still remember being excited about OS/2 coming to the market...  ;)