# Ubuntu 17.04 - how to set Alt+Shift as keyboard layout switch?

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I've upgraded Ubuntu 16.04 with Gnome Flashback to 16.10 and then to 17.04.

After that, switching keyboard layout was set to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, but didn't work. What works is the default <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.

When I want to change in the new UI for keyboard shortcuts, I can't - it doesn't register this shortcut. It seems the shortcuts need to contain some character.

I have tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/816650/41425) but it doesn't work either. As a stopgap I am using `['<Shift><Alt>X']`.

*PS: I wonder why do things that work need to be constantly changed. Does  every new version need a new way of configuring the system? And why `Alt+Shift`, which worked on every system I have ever seen since Windows 3.11 in 90's, need to change now? ...*

Comment: Are you using 17.04 or 17.10? Is a bit confusing to me

Comment: There was a discussion recently about <Alt>+<Shift> on GNOME Flashback. You may want to study the thread, e.g. [this message](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-discuss/2017-May/017430.html) posted by a Flashback developer.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson thanks, but it basically says it works, while it does not, as I wrote above.

Comment: I have same problem, can't set Caps Lock as a switch combination

Comment: If something does not work then please open/report bugs.

Comment: I put [some positive rant](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-discuss/2017-May/017427.html) on developer list without any success. I can't set up <Alt+Shift>  as keyboard layout switcher in gnome-flashback session on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I do not know how they did it. It may be related to well known old [bug 1218322](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1218322) or new [bug 1687466](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1687466).
I need to do my work, so I switched to MATE Desktop Environment and it is great!

Answer (score 2):

Start Gnome Tweak tool

Typing -> Switching to another layout -> Alt+Shift (or CapsLock, ...)

Comment: very odd place to find this setting

Comment: @pcnate yes. that's why I wrote the answer